# Let's say that a graph has 28 edges and 5 components. What is the largest number of vertices that the graph can have?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let's say that a graph has 28 edges and 5 components. What is the largest number of vertices that the graph can have?

I'm pretty confused about components in general, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

Two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in the same component if and only if there is a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$. So you can think of the components of a graph as separate graphs if that helps.

Suppose a component has $e$ edges. Then it can have at most $e+1$ vertices; you can prove this by induction on $e$. One way to achieve this maximum is simply to string the vertices out in a line.

If a graph has $28$ edges and $5$ components, let the number of edges in each component be $e_1,\ldots,e_5$. Then the maximum number of vertices is $(e_1+1)+\cdots+(e_5+1)$, which is equal to $33$ (because $e_1+\cdots+e_5=28$).

Comment: There are other ways to achieve the maximum number of vertices for a component containing a given number of edges.  Any graph without loops should work.

Comment: @RobertShore: you are right, of course. I have edited my answer to preclude any misundertandings.

Answer (score 1):

In order to minimize the shared vertices we choose to  have four edges with two vertices each and one path with $24$ edges and 25 vertices. The total vertices end up being $8+25 =33$

Thus the maximum number of vertices is $33$.